# Custom types vhdl in port declaration

Tags: vhdl

I want to used a custom out port for a program.
I've read [Can custom types be used in port declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16872950/can-custom-types-be-used-in-port-declaration) but it doesn't resolve my problem.

In my_package.vhd:

```vhdl
package my_package is
    type custom_type is (a1,a2,a3,a4);
end package;
```

Then in my vhdl program:

```vhdl
use work.my_package.all;

entity test is 
    port(testInt : out custom_type);
end entity test;

architecture test_a of test is
    type custom_type is (a1,a2,a3,a4);
    signal s:  custom_type;
begin
    testInt <= s;
end architecture;
```

But, now I have the error:

> type of identifier "s" does not agree with its usage as "custom_type" type

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 6.2 Type declarations "The types created by the elaboration of distinct type definitions are distinct types."  12.3 Visibility "A declaration is said to be hidden within (part of) an inner declarative region if the inner region contains a homograph of this declaration; the outer declaration is then hidden within the immediate scope of the inner homograph."  The second declaration of custom_type hides the package declaration in the architecture body (an inner declarative region, the use clause appears in the root declarative region). comment out the inner declaration.

Answer (score 1):

You declared custom_type in `my_package` already. Because you declared it again inside the architecture of the `test` entity, you have effectively created a new type. Because VHDL is strongly typed, the type in the entity is different (and not compatible with) the one declared in the package. The compiler will use the local declared type over the one from the package.

Simply delete the one from the architecture and use the one that comes from the package that is already visible via the `use work.my_package.all;` clause.